# Angular 2 Basic Authentication not working

Tags: angular, typescript, header, basic-authentication

I'm trying to connect/ do a POST request to an API with Angular2, It's a very simple API with a Basic Authentication password.
When disabling the password on the api everything works like expected. But when I enable the Basic Authentication Angular can no longer connect to the API. In Postman everything works. I tried the following without success.

I've got two headers "Content-Type" and "Authorization"

```
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

I've tried these two headers.

```
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(Username + ":" + Password)); 
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic VXNlcm5hbWU6UGFzc3dvcmQ=");
```

The only thing I can find is that in the RAW request headers there's only a line with the header names but the values are missing:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization, content-type
```

Raw headers:

```
#Request Headers
OPTIONS /shipment HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4200/address
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: DUPLICATE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408413/angular2-http-post-how-to-send-authorization-header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 http post - how to send Authorization header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408413/angular2-http-post-how-to-send-authorization-header)

Comment: If this is duplicate, then flag it as a duplicate :)

Comment: Please look at the dates before you flag it as a duplicate ;)

Comment: Good catch Peter!!

Answer (score 26):

Simplified version to add custom headers to your request:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

   constructor(private _http: Http) {}

   call(url): Observable<any> {
      let username: string = 'username';
      let password: string = 'password';
      let headers: Headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
      headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      return this._http.post(url, data, {headers: headers})
    }
}
```

It's hard to determine where you went wrong, because the lack of code of the actual `http` call you do. But this example should work for you

Comment: I think that an issue is inside of _normalizedNames {"authorization" => "Authorization"}. It shall be {"authorization" => "basic VXNlcm5hbWU6UGFzc3dvcmQ"}.

Comment: @Skyware Headers are case insensitive :)

Comment: That`s good to know. However, It should be normalized to "authorization" => "basic xxx" not to "authorization" => "Authorization". Angular 2 normalize an authorization header badly.

Comment: Ahh, that's what you meant. And yes, I agree with you

Comment: I think that the solution is on back-end side as the solution mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408413/angular2-http-post-how-to-send-authorization-header

Comment: I had to assign the new headers like this in order to make it work: `headers = headers.append(...);`

Answer (score 3):

[jrcastillo](https://github.com/jrcastillo) suggested another option [here](https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo/issues/34)

I spent ***so many hours*** trying to fix this and this one liner solved my problem.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
}
```

I was a bit more specific in the end as this effected my **/login** path so I did the following instead:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/**");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem in my application.

As you can see the request that is sended is not POST but OPTION ( pre verification)

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

You must allowed the OPTIONS request at your API  side. 
If you have Spring application  you can just add this to Spring Security configuration :

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                **.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()**
(..)

}
```

In my case it works

Answer (score 2):

This solved my issues:
[Angular2 http post - how to send Authorization header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408413/angular2-http-post-how-to-send-authorization-header)

> Ok. I found problem.
>
> It was not on the Angular side. To be honest, there were no problem at all.
>
> Reason why I was unable to perform my request succesfuly was that my server app was not properly handling OPTIONS request.
>
> Why OPTIONS, not POST? My server app is on different host, then frontend. Because of CORS my browser was converting POST to OPTION: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/
>
> With help of this answer: Standalone Spring OAuth2 JWT Authorization Server + CORS
>
> I implemented proper filter on my server-side app.
>
> Thanks to @Supamiu - the person which fingered me that I am not sending POST at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the backend server. Any browser sends a preflight request making a cross-origin request. The backend server in this case is not handling the preflight request successfully. Try doing the cors configuration on the backend server. That will resolve this issue.