# http post - how to send Authorization header?

Tags: rest, http, authentication, angular, typescript

How do you add headers to your http request in Angular2 RC6?
I got following code:

```
login(login: String, password: String): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log(login);
    console.log(password);
    this.cookieService.removeAll();
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization","Basic YW5ndWxhci13YXJlaG91c2Utc2VydmljZXM6MTIzNDU2");
    this.http.post(AUTHENTICATION_ENDPOINT + "?grant_type=password&scope=trust&username=" + login + "&password=" + password, null, {headers: headers}).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
    //some return
}
```

The problem is, that angular doesn't add Authorization header. Instead of that, in request I can see following additional headers:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
```

and sdch added in Accept-Encoding:

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
```

Unfornately there is no Authorization header. How should I add it correctly?

Whole request sent by my code looks as follow:

```
OPTIONS /oauth/token?grant_type=password&scope=trust&username=asdf&password=asdf HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:3002
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3002/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,pl;q=0.6
```

Comment: Have you tried to provide your own request options instead? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35047978/4102561

Comment: @Supamiu Unfornately this solution doesn't work.

I tried:
this.http._defaultOptions.headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic YW5ndWxhci13YXJlaG91c2Utc2VydmljZXM6MTIzNDU2');

And got same results

Comment: The request you show in your question is the `OPTIONS` preflight request, can you please add the POST request ?(should be just after this one in your network tab)

Comment: DUPLICATE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368794/angular-2-basic-authentication-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Basic Authentication not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368794/angular-2-basic-authentication-not-working)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ok. I found problem.

It was not on the Angular side. To be honest, there were no problem at all.

Reason why I was unable to perform my request succesfuly was that my server app was not properly handling OPTIONS request.

Why OPTIONS, not POST? My server app is on different host, then frontend. Because of CORS my browser was converting POST to OPTION:
http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/

With help of this answer:
[Standalone Spring OAuth2 JWT Authorization Server + CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632200/standalone-spring-oauth2-jwt-authorization-server-cors?lq=1)

I implemented proper filter on my server-side app.

Thanks to @Supamiu - the person which fingered me that I am not sending POST at all.

Comment: It sends `OPTIONS` as a preflight request and then the `POST` if everything goes fine. It's not replacing `POST` with `OPTIONS`.

Answer (score 18):

you need RequestOptions

```
 let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});  
 headers.append('Authorization','Bearer ')
 let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
 return this.http.post(APIname,body,options)
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

for more check this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html)

Answer (score 10):

I believe you need to map the result before you subscribe to it. You configure it like this:

```
  updateProfileInformation(user: User) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', this.constants.jsonContentType);

    var t = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + t;
    var body = JSON.stringify(user);

    return this.http.post(this.constants.userUrl + "UpdateUser", body, { headers: headers })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        var result = response.json();
        return result;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError)
      .subscribe(
      status => this.statusMessage = status,
      error => this.errorMessage = error,
      () => this.completeUpdateUser()
      );
  }
```

Comment: The point of question is not how to deal with http **response**, but how to add proper header to **request**.

For sure I checked your proposal - it doesn't work, sent headers are still same.

Comment: What version of angular you got?

Comment: I'm using angular RC6

Comment: Did you make some additional configuration of http request?

Comment: Huh...On my end it is not working... Don't know why... This is my http ver: "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.6", are you sure you have same?

Comment: Could you show me headers which are sent with your request?

Comment: Its in my code sample... Content-Type and Authorization

Comment: headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + t; this line missing closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 6):

If you are like me, and starring at your angular/ionic typescript, which looks like..

```
  getPdf(endpoint: string): Observable<Blob> {
    let url = this.url + '/' + endpoint;
    let token = this.msal.accessToken;
    console.log(token);
    return this.http.post<Blob>(url, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders(
        {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://localhost:5100',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
          'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
          'Accept': '*/*',
        }),
        //responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
      });
  }
```

And while you are setting options but can't seem to figure why they aren't anywhere..

Well.. if you were like me and started this `post` from a copy/paste of a `get`, then...

Change to:

```
  getPdf(endpoint: string): Observable<Blob> {
    let url = this.url + '/' + endpoint;
    let token = this.msal.accessToken;
    console.log(token);
    return this.http.post<Blob>(url, null, { //  <-----  notice the null  *****
      headers: new HttpHeaders(
        {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
          'Accept': '*/*',
        }),
        //responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
      });
  }
```

Comment: `Access-Control` headers are set by the server, not the client as is `Content-Type`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. This is my solution using angular documentation and firebase Token:

```
getService()  {

const accessToken=this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getToken().then(res=>{
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': res
    })
  };
  return this.http.get('Url',httpOptions)
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
}); }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the detailed answer to the question:

> Pass data into the HTTP header from the Angular side (Please note I am
>   using  Angular4.0+ in the application).

There is more than one way we can pass data into the headers.
The syntax is different but all means the same.

```
// Option 1 
 const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Authorization': 'my-auth-token',
     'ID': emp.UserID,
   })
 };


// Option 2

let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append('Authorization', 'my-auth-token');
httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append('ID', '001');
httpHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');    

let options = {headers:httpHeaders};


// Option 1
   return this.http.post(this.url + 'testMethod', body,httpOptions)

// Option 2
   return this.http.post(this.url + 'testMethod', body,options)
```

In the call you can find the field passed as a header as shown in the image below :
[image]

Still, if you are facing the issues like.. (You may need to change the backend/WebAPI side)

- Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
  ''Access-Control-Allow-Origin'' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ''http://localhost:4200'' is therefore not allowed
  access
- Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.

Find my detailed answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52620468/3454221

Answer (score 1):

if you are a ruby on rails developer and you facing a similar issue, this is because of the config of your backend: especially in api mode
so with
**gem 'rack-cors' installed**

goto app/config/cors.rb

## Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
   allow do
     origins 'domain_name:port or just use *'

     resource '*',
       headers: :any,
       methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
       credentials: true
   end
 end
```

the *credentials:true line does the trick
then in your SessionController
after a user is valid for login
insert a line(this assumes you are using gem 'jwt')

```
token = user.generate_jwt
response.headers['Authorization'] = token
```

generate_jwt is a method called in model User , it is

```
JWT.encode(id, key, alogrithm)
```

If you use django, that is already taken care for you
you just have to use
installed app: **restframework_simplejwt**