# Response for preflight has invalid http status code 404 in my angular project while consuming web api

Tags: angular, post, asp.net-web-api, preflight

I know that it's CORS problem. I have enabled cors in web api server side. Get method is working fine but while dealing with post method I am facing problem . Please some one answer me with very simple post example both on web api and client side. With explanation of how to deal with preflight, options etc..

Console

1) zone.js:2935 OPTIONS http://localhost:49975/api/Add_Client_/postgoals 404 (Not Found)

2) Failed to load http://localhost:49975/api/Add_Client_/postgoals: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404.

web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>

    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Angular Post method

```
    save_Goals(){

  let headers : Headers= new Headers();
  //headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  //headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","true");
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type');

  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post('http://localhost:49975/api/Add_Client_/postgoals', {goal:'foo'},options)
   .map(res =>  res.json());
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: usually CORS problems don't come with 404 error (unless manually set server side). They can even come with 200 ok status. What is the CORS message in the console? adding some details could help too, such as are there custom headers added? what is the response header? (without showing sensible values)

Comment: Yes I have custom headers added in web.config file.

Comment: please edit the original question, it's hard to read code in comments. So, amongst other things, the `OPTIONS` request is made to check if custom headers are allowed by the server, did you allow them? Knowing the exact CORS error if there is one would still be useful.

Comment: I have edited the question .. please go through, I stuck with it from many days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a work around. what i did is i removed custom headers from web.config file. i.e,

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>

    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This content i **removed**

and in **WebApiConfig.cs** i did following changes

```
var enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins:"*",headers:"*",methods:"*");

            var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;

            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

            config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);
```

and **Controller** Looks like this.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
    [RoutePrefix("api/Add_Client_")]
    public class Add_Client_Controller : ApiController
    {
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("PostGoals")]
        public string PostGoals(string goal)
        {
            Goal g = new Goal();
            g.Goals = goal;
            db.Goals.Add(g);
            int res = db.SaveChanges();

            return ("Success");
        }
}
```

and **Angular POST** Method looks like following

```
 save_Goals(){

  let headers : Headers= new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type');

      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:49975/api/Add_Client_/PostGoals?goal=check',options)
       .map(res =>  res.json());
    }
```

This is work around to send data with URL.

Answer (score 2):

I am late but still wants to post the answer so to other it can be helpful.
Below code works for me like a charm!

Here is the detailed answer to the question:

> Pass data into the HTTP header from the Angular side (Please note I am
>   using  Angular4.0+ in the application).

There is more than one way we can pass data into the headers.
The syntax is different but all means the same.

```
// Option 1 
 const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Authorization': 'my-auth-token',
     'ID': emp.UserID,
   })
 };


// Option 2

let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append('Authorization', 'my-auth-token');
httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append('ID', '001');
httpHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');    

let options = {headers:httpHeaders};


// Option 1
   return this.http.post(this.url + 'testMethod', body,httpOptions)

// Option 2
   return this.http.post(this.url + 'testMethod', body,options)
```

In the call you can find the field passed as a header as shown in the image below :
[image]

> 2. Make changes at the backEnd/Web API side

Add new WebApiConfig file and add below content.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", headers: "ID", methods: "*") { SupportsCredentials = true }); // In the Header define all the header by comma cepration or you can write * if it works for you.
            /config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

In the Global.asax.cs file add below event

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","ID");// In the Header define all the header by comma cepration or you can write * if it works for you.
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

And at the Web API side you can fetch that code with below statement :

```
 if (Request.Headers.Contains("ID"))
            {
                var ID= Request.Headers.GetValues("ID").First();
            }
```

you can follow these steps for below errors :

- Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
  ''Access-Control-Allow-Origin'' header is present on the requested
  resource. Origin ''http://localhost:4200'' is therefore not allowed
  access
- Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.

This code works for me, I am able to pass ID in the HTTP header and same I can retrieve at web API side.

Thanks and Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

also u can use chrome extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc

set header type  application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type');
```