# Angular 5 http.post Authorization header is not set

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, angular5, spring-security-oauth2

```
const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic d2ViYXBwOjExMTE=',
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' : 'Authorization',
            'Accept' : 'application/json'
          })
        };
    return this.http.post(oauth2_token_endpoint, {}, httpOptions);
```

Screen shot of Http Request is:
[image]

Please help.

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408413/http-post-how-to-send-authorization-header

Answer (score 0):

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };
```

Comment: import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';