# HttpServletRequest request.getHeader() is always null?

Tags: angular, spring, security, filter, token

I have the problem that `HttpServletRequest request.getHeader("Authorization")` is always null value, I send with Angular service my get request with headers but these never seem to arrive.

I'm using Spring Boot as my REST server, and Angular as my front-end.

**user.service.ts**

```js
getUserDetails(username): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-key-quotes
      'Authorization': sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
    });
    // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-shorthand
    console.log(`http://localhost:8080/users/` + username, { headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/users/` + username, { headers: headers }).pipe(
      map(
        userData => {
          console.log(userData);
          return userData;
        }
      ));
  }
```

**JWTRequestFilter.java**

```java
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    String username = null;
    String jwtToken = null;
    // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
    // only the Token
    if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
        try {
            username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
        }
    } else {
        logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
    }
    // Once we get the token validate it.
    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
        // authentication
        if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                    .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
            // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
            // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

**The Network Traffic:**

[image]

When I'm going to the account page where I call the get request `http://localhost:8080/users/testUser`

The requestTokenHeader is always null?

Comment: please check your network tab for cross verification, is authorization token going in service header or not.

Comment: @FarhatZaman I've added an image of the network traffic

Comment: may be this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39411480/7541317) will be helpfull for you.