# CORS preflight request in Spring Data REST

Tags: authentication, angular, spring-boot, cors, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Boot / Spring Data REST service allowing access to a number of resources. Some of this resources (eg. `/detections`) are freely accessible, other (eg. `/users`) require basic HTTP auth. By testing the REST service with CURL everything works as expected. The problems arise when I try to access the service from an Angular2 web application.

In this case I have no problem when accessing the unprotected resources `http://api.mydomain.com/detections` :

```
this.http.get(this.DETECTIONS_API_ENDPOINT).subscribe(
                            response => {
                              ...
                            },
                            error => {
                              ...
                            }
                    );
```

But if I try to access a protected resource `http://api.mydomain.com/users` by passing the required headers with the correct username and password:

```
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username+':'+password)); 

    return this.http.get(this.USERS_API_ENDPOINT, { body: "", headers: headers }).subscribe(
                            response => {
                              ...
                            },
                            error => {
                              ...
                            }
                    );
```

I get (in Firefox console) an error which saying `cross-origin request blocked... Reason: CORS preflight request unsuccessfull` (please note that this is my translation from Italian. I couldn't find the exact corresponding error message in English. The only difference between the two calls seems to be the passing of the headers in the second case, which triggers the sending of an `OPTIONS` instead of a `GET` request.

This is my spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfigurationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private Md5PasswordEncoder md5PasswordEncoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService myAppUserService;

    /**
     * HttpSecurity URL configuration settings. Configure authentication necessary for POST but not for GET
     */

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/detections").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/detections/search/findTop5ByOrderByTimestampDesc").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/roles").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("**").authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic().and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }


    /**
     * Sets custom MyAppUserService bean as user detail service
     */

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myAppUserService).passwordEncoder(md5PasswordEncoder);
    }

}
```

This is the CORS filter configuration; I added this class following the suggestion at [Spring Data Rest and Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724994/spring-data-rest-and-cors), and it initially solved my CORS-access problem for accessing the unprotected resources. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in the case of the protected resource:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfigurationCors {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true); // you USUALLY want this
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS"); // I added this in a second phase, but nothing changes
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/40374505/4793153

Comment: It's not very clear to me how this should work: I tried to replace my `MyAppConfigurationCors` configuration class with the Filter component as in the question text, then tried to put the `if("OPTIONS"...` test in the `doFilter` method, but I am not sure I'm doing things right. In any case I still got the error ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to Spring Documentation on how to integrate [CORS and Spring Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html).

CORS must be processed first:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
            .cors().and()
            ...
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the the cors filter before the first Spring Security Filter i.e. ChannelProcessingFilter. The following piece of code will help explain more.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http.requiresChannel().antMatchers("/*").requires(ANY_CHANNEL).and()
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/customer/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/signin").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/**").permitAll().and()
.addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
.and().csrf().disable();
}
```

If any other info is required visit this -: 
http://javamusings.com/enabling-cors-support-in-spring-framework/. 
Note -: I am the author of the post.