# Angular 2 need help sending HTTP request for Oauth

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth, angular2-http

How do I send an http request in Angular 2 like this with that 'at' sign:

http://TEST@localhost:8082/api/auth/oauth/token

I have the route just like that, but when I send the request it ends up taking the TEST@ out.

From Chrome Dev tools:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8082/api/auth/oauth/token
```

EDIT:

Actually knowing what i'm trying to do is called helps, but I couldn't seem to find it on google anywhere. It's called Basic Access Authentication (wiki in comments below)

This question is resolved by:

[Angular 2 Basic Authentication not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368794/angular-2-basic-authentication-not-working)

Comment: the question is why do you have that `@` in the host?

Comment: I believe the authentication service I have uses it so that it knows who is calling it. If you don't put it with a valid username, it will return a 401. That is my issue right now.

Comment: usualy it's `user:password@host`, but that's for human being typing an address, you need to pass a header...

Comment: How would the header look?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side

Comment: Huh. It says some modern browsers don't support it anymore. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138958/discussion-between-alex-palacios-and-n00dl3).