# How to connect an Angular2+ application to an outside API?

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers

I need some assistance on examples of connecting an outside API to an Angular Application that has a username and password for authentication. I know how to connect an outside API that doesn't require authentication but I am trying to connect to an API that has a username and password as well as a proxy connection. And I am unsure how that is passed in the application? Any examples or help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you need to provide more details on how the API accepts the username and password. Like query param, request headers etc.,

Comment: what is the API's request method GET or POST?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but I believe it will be through request headers. Also it is a GET request

Comment: To get better answers, you should probably include more information about this proxy and API, what you have tried, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The user and password are sending as headers then these headers you need put inside of Post method in the third parameter. This is an example.

```
      let username: string = 'username';
      let password: string = 'password';
      let headers: Headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
      headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      this._http.post(url, data, {headers: headers})
```

Answer reference [Http Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38369923/6651984)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19394334)

Comment: @cnishina is it better like that?

Comment: Looks better. The initial question is vague.